# Android custom view causing force close

Tags: android, custom-view

I have a custom view in src > myproject.test > HomeView

In my main layout xml I have the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/home_root"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <myproject.test.HomeView
        android:id="@+id/home_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    </myproject.test.HomeView>

</LinearLayout>
```

In the HomeActivity I have a call like this in the onCreate method.

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
HomeView mHomeView = (HomeView) this.findViewById(R.id.home_view);
```

The app force closed when the setContentView method is called. It seems that my main xml is not correct.

Any ideas?

Comment: @EBoMiko where can I see that?

Comment: Call `adb logcat V` from a console. That should be your very first instinct whenever you get a force close.

Comment: How are you creating HomeView? Show us that class.

Comment: `home_root` is the name of your layout, Why `R.layour.main`?

Comment: @Falmarri I have loaded the HomeView on the main activity by using setContentView and the contents of HomeView loaded without a problem.

Comment: @Frayser main.xml is the name of my layout and Android interprets this as R.layout.main. all the samples on the Android dev site use this.

Comment: You still haven't posted the output of the logcat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean its not getting to the

```
HomeView mHomeView = (HomeView) this.findViewById(R.id.home_view);
```

and crashing on the line before it?

Check if your constructor is

```
HomeView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs){
     super(context, attrs);
```

and not

```
HomeView(final Context context){
     super(context);
```

you need the AttributeSet

Comment: yes, if I comment out the HomeView setup line it still force closes

Comment: How do you initialize your home view? could you show some code, and the output from logcat

Comment: Just out of intrest, is your layout also called main.xml ? and is it in the layout dir?

Comment: it was the constructor. thanx

Answer (score 0):

Check constructors that your HomeView implements:

```
 public HomeView(Context context, AttributeSet atts) {
     super(context, atts); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android = 
      http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/home_root"
    android:orientation="vertical"
```

None of my layouts have `@+id`. Maybe you should set the view to  `home_root`.  Check with you *R.java* for the name of the layout, or try

```
setContentView(R.layout.home_root);
```